# Extract names from a ID column (create a new vector with each occurence appearing only once)

Tags: r

I try to automatize the extraction of names from a .csv file. In my database, names of animals are in the first column and I would like to obtain a vector into which I can have each name appearing only once. Indeed, in the original file, for each animal I have hundreds of measurments. Of course, I may be able to create this vector by writting it down directly. However this code should come into an annual procedure into which those names could change from a year to another.

For the moment I have tried a loop as follow :

```
length_name <- length(dataset$Nom)
name <- function(Nom){
 for (i in 1:(length_name)){
    stock <- c(i)
    if (i!=(i+1)){
      stock <- stock + c(i+1)
    }
  return(stock)  
  }
}
```

I expected a vector with all the different names (I'm looking for 39 of them) and only a `[1] 3` has been returned. Note that I've indicate earlier in my code that this column contains string of characters using as.character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop, you can just do:

```
unique(dataset$Nom)
```

If that doesn't work, please post a reproducible dataset.

Comment: I feel like I'm really stupid... It didn't work out with unique because of the 'as.character(dataset$Nom)'. Many thanks for your really quick answer !